Can I add all my projects having sub git repositories in a top level git repo?
I have all my code in a folder in which I want to initialize a git repo for all the code. This folder has many projects. Some projects have a .git folder in them and are a git repository. I want to add all these projects to the top-level git repo.
Even if I can skip the one's which are already a git repo, can I add the rest of the files automatically?
I have tried:
git add .
This gives me a submodule error.

Try using git submodule in your top level git repo as follows:
git submodule add https://github.com/RealCoder24/Python.git
It will look something like this.
https://github.com/RealCoder24/Submodule.git
Notice that it has a file .gitmodules. Now you can enter inside the submodule (here Pyhton) and commit.
Replace this with your https/ssh link.
You can look for more details in here https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules.

Thanks for this. I wanted to ask that some of the repos aren't hosted on Git Hub or anywhere. They are just using git. How can I add those?

@AbdullahBinRashid I think you have something like this:
TopLevel--SubREPO.
Now if git is initialized in both TopLevel and SubREPO directory, then you can go into TopLevel directory and type following command:
"git submodule add  SubREPO".
This will ink SubREPO as a Submodule within TopLevel.
